# yii cookies set httpOnly

Tags: cookies, yii, components, config, httponly

In yii default option CHttpCookie->httpOnly installed in false as possible during the entire application configuration set by default httpOnly = true?

P.S. Transfer options do not offer, do not want to go into third-party extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at all. `CHttpCookie` in Yii is used directly within its constructor, ie: `$cookie = new CHttpCookie //...`. So there is no way to inject params.
You could set this per component as described [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/12849-chttpcookie-httponly/) but it is still not global setting.

But you could extend `CHttpRequest` and ovveride `addCookie` and `removeCookie` and force `httpOnly` there. To ovveride simple create your own `HttpRequest` class extending from `CHttpRequest` and define it components use like that:

```
// .. other components
'request' => [
                'class' => 'HttpRequest',
// optional:
//              'enableCsrfValidation' => true,
//              'enableCookieValidation' => true,
          ],
// .. other components
```

(I used php 5.4 array notation, should not be a problem for you?:))
Other way is to clone framework git repo and set this to true...